How does cognitive therapy work?
A depressed person has a negative self-conception. Cognitive therapists believe that the negative self-conception is the cause of the depression. This doesn't make sense to me.
Suppose a person with depression is unemployed, uneducated, idle, regarded by others as having little worth, and therefore they're socially isolated. Consequently, they too regard themselves as having little worth. Surely their appraisal of the situation can't be the source of their low mood. Indeed, it would seem almost delusional for them to have any other self-conception given the circumstances. How could they possibly believe that they're "just as good as anyone else" when it's unlikely that most others would actually take that position unless they were being polite?
It seems as though it would be impossible and arguably not even desirable for them to esteem themselves highly and feel good under those circumstances, and yet so far as I can tell that's precisely what cognitive therapists would attempt to do. But that approach seems destined to fail given that the negative self-conception has some basis in fact and is the social consensus. I can understand remission through changing conditions but not through cognitive restructuring. What am I missing?
